# jsontostructs to Row in spark structured streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark 2.2 and i'm trying to read the JSON messages from Kafka, transform them to `DataFrame` and have them as a `Row`:

```
spark
    .readStream()
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "topic")
    .load()
    .select(col("value").cast(StringType).as("col"))
    .writeStream()
    .format("console")
    .start();
```

with this I can achieve:

```
+--------------------+
|                 col|
+--------------------+
|{"myField":"somet...|
+--------------------+
```

I wanted something more like this:

```
+--------------------+
|             myField|
+--------------------+
|"something"         |
+--------------------+
```

I tried to use `from_json` function using `struct`:

```
DataTypes.createStructType(
    new StructField[] {
            DataTypes.createStructField("myField", DataTypes.StringType)
    }
)
```

but I only got:

```
+--------------------+
|  jsontostructs(col)|
+--------------------+
|[something]         |
+--------------------+
```

then I tried to use `explode` but I only got Exception saying:

```
cannot resolve 'explode(`col`)' due to data type mismatch: 
input to function explode should be array or map type, not 
StructType(StructField(...
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're almost there, just select the right thing. `from_json` returns a `struct` column matching the schema. If schema (JSON representation) looks like this:

```
{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"myField","type":"string","nullable":false,"metadata":{}}]}
```

you'll get nested object equivalent to:

```
root
 |-- jsontostructs(col): struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- myField: string (nullable = false)
```

You can use [`getField`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#getField-java.lang.String-) (or `getItem`) method to select specific field

```
df.select(from_json(col("col"), schema).getField("myField").alias("myField"));
```

or `.*` to select all top level fields in the `struct`:

```
df.select(from_json(col("col"), schema).alias("tmp")).select("tmp.*");
```

although for single `string` column, [`get_json_object`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#get_json_object-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-) should be more than enough:

```
df.select(get_json_object(col("col"), "$.myField"));
```